# Defining a service in setup of Jenkins on GKE using Helm

Tags: jenkins, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy a Jenkins on Google Cloud (GKE) using Helm as described in https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins
What changes in the file values.yaml have I to do in order to access Jenkins GUI ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a whole lot you need to modify. In the `values.yaml`, you will find a section:

```
serviceType: ClusterIP
```

You can either change `ClusterIP` to `LoadBalancer` and use:

```
kubectl get svc
```

to get the url you need to access the Jenkins UI, or keep `ClusterIP` as it is and use [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod). You can then run the same `get svc` command above and get the IP used to access the Jenkins UI.